# How add pages buttons to pager jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

By default on pager i have only Prev, Next, First and Last buttons.

But i need also have buttons for each page.

I need this location for the buttons:

```
[FIRST] [PREV] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [NEXT] [LAST]
```

Please, help.

Comment: Having worked with jqGrid alot, For what you're asking, you have 2 options: 1) Edit the source (yuk!) 2) use the `loadComplete1` event to write a long function adding these buttons manually

Comment: thanks, That's why I did not find this in the documentation.